# how to insert UITextField at Top row in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an iphone app in which i want that when app load it should just one cell with textfield when user enter any data in first cell it should new cell with entered data and first cell should be empty as editable.
I am making but it shows same value in above cell also.

[image]

here is the code

```
           -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {



    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


   cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabelsales.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   }



   if (indexPath.section==0) {
    tagInputField =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 6, 250, 26)];
    tagInputField.tag = 2;
    tagInputField.delegate = self;
     tagInputField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    tagInputField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad-Pro" size:8];
    [tagInputField setText:@" "];

    tagInputField.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];

    [cell addSubview:tagInputField];

    cell.textLabel.text=@"";

    return cell;

    }

    if (indexPath.section==1) {
    UIButton *crossButton =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 8, 18, 18)];
    //crossButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    crossButton.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross.png"]];
    [cell addSubview:crossButton];
    cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
    cell.textLabel.text =[tagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [crossButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;


    }        

    }
```

Comment: The problem is in your code. You need to share you code.

Comment: @SarwarErfan added code please check

Comment: Try with the updated code I posted. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabelsales.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    for (UIView *subView in cell.subviews)
    {
        if (subView.tag == 2 || subView.tag == 22) 
        {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }


    if(indexPath.section==0){
        tagInputField =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 6, 250, 26)];
        tagInputField.tag = 2;
        tagInputField.delegate = self;
        tagInputField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        tagInputField.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad-Pro" size:8];
        [tagInputField setText:@" "];
        tagInputField.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
        [cell addSubview:tagInputField];
        cell.textLabel.text=@"";
        return cell;
    }

    if(indexPath.section==1) {
        UIButton *crossButton =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 8, 18, 18)];
        *crossButton.tag = 22; //use a tag value that is not used for any other subview
        //crossButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        crossButton.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cross.png"]];
        [cell addSubview:crossButton];
        cell.textLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
        cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
        cell.textLabel.text =[tagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [crossButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image about the sign you are talking about?